# SQL Server 2017 adding additional column to order date field

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which has a date and month per record and I want to add an additional column ordering each with the column being named month-order. Please see the example output below:

```
month-order month-year  Load_date    Name
-----------------------------------------
1           Jan-20      2020-01-31   Ryan
1           Jan-20      2020-01-31   Paul
2           Feb-20      2020-02-28   Ryan
2           Feb-20      2020-02-28   Paul
3           Feb-20      2020-02-28   Ryan
3           Feb-20      2020-02-28   Paul
```

I have tried using the rank over function but no success, and don't want to create a month order using a reference table to avoid having extra maintenance.

Any ideas on how I could populate the month-order with code would be appreciated

Comment: Please explain the logic.  It is not obvious.

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff, it's not obvious what the logic is. Why are two otherwise identical rows give different `month-order` (2 vs 3)?

Comment: where month-year is jan-20 and load_date is 2020-01-31 the order needs to be 1. The month order does not need to be a unique, just unique to the date columns, so for the month of Jan there are two rows but the order is still 1 for both

Comment: How is a load date of 2020-02-28 with a month-year of Feb-20 be both a month order of 2 and 3?    The last 4 rows in your sample appear to be duplicates except that 1 set has a month order of 2 and the other has a month order of 3.  Can you clarify the logic?

Comment: sorry made a typo, the output should look like this: month-order month-year  Load_date    Name
-----------------------------------------
1           Jan-20      2020-01-31   Ryan
1           Jan-20      2020-01-31   Paul
2           Feb-20      2020-02-28   Ryan
2           Feb-20      2020-02-28   Paul
3           Mar-20      2020-03-31   Ryan
3           Mar-20      2020-03-31   Paul

Comment: If month_order is based on Load_date and if Load_date column is a date datatype just use month() on Load_date.  Add `MONTH(Load_date) as month_order` to your select.

Comment: I actually solved it myself by having the month and date columns in a sub query selecting distinct values, and then applied a row number to that result set to get the order

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you want to enumerate each name separately:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by name order by month_year) as month_order
from t;
```

Comment: I don't know what would be right, but I'm confident this isn't. The order by within the window function seems to reference field that doesn't exist.

Comment: @SteveLovell . . . That should be `month_year`.